# deploying a versioned WAR file to tomcat

Tags: maven-2, tomcat

I was wondering what would be the best practice to deploy a maven packaged WAR file to tomcat. 
Using maven release plugin I get a versioned war file for my project
eg: myservice-1.0.0.war

I would like to deploy it to tomcat so that I can access it as follows
eg: http://localhost:8080/myservice

By default tomcat explodes the war file as a directory with a name myservice-1.0.0 under CATALINA_HOME/webapps. But I want to to explode the war as a directory with a name myservice for the reasons mentioned above.

I know I can simply rename myservice-1.0.0.war >> myservice.war and then deploy it in Tomcat.

I wanted to find out what others do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it by mentioning myservice as artifactId and final name and using maven cargo plugin to deploy to tomcat.
http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Tips

Comment: thanks. I do use artifact id as myservice but I also need to version the project which in my case is 1.0.0
What tip in particular are you referring to in the link you provided?

Comment: ok... in build tag there is an option to provide finalName which becomes the name of war. Did you try setting it?

Comment: oh cool thanks. I forgot about that. Yes, that's an option, I could definitely try that. I am still interested to find out how others approach it for their production builds.

Answer (score 2):

You can package file /META-INF/context.xml with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Context>
<Context path="myapp">
</Context>
```

See documentation at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  What worked for me was inserting this properties element into the cargo deployable configuration:

```
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>org.something</groupId>
                        <artifactId>something-idm-esb</artifactId>
                        <properties>
                            <context>something-idm-esb</context>
                        </properties>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </deployable>
```

Without this properties element, the app would be deployed to localhost:8080/something-idm-esb-0.9.14.2 which is not what the app needs at runtime.  With the properties section, the app is deployed to localhost:8080/something-idm-esb/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming the war file you could do this:

Just add following in your tomcat-dir/conf/server.xml in between `<Host>..<\Host>` tags.

for : myservice-1.0.0.war file

```
<Context path="/myservice" docBase="/myservice-1.0.0" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

[Reference](http://techlightening.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/tomcat-change-default-web-application/)

Comment: That's reasonable for major versions, but if your version changes often you might prefer something more automated. I might mix your solution with the above, to trim the minor version number from filename.